# A driving offence including overtaking vehicles frequently from their left and right

Tags: word-usage

What's "overtake vehicles from their left and right" called in English? You know moving like you are drawing a squiggly line on the highway in your car.

If there is a special legal term as a driving offence and also there is an informal word to describe this action, please mention both.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: In the US we drive on the right, so you should pass other vehicles on the left. However the phrase "overtake vehicles from their left and right" indicates that the offense was weaving through traffic in a manner that was deemed reckless. It would seem to indicate that there were two lanes of traffic on the highway, such as an interstate highway here in US.

Comment: Are you talking about how an actor would drive in movies, zooming past cars left and right ?

Comment: As MaxW says the offense would be probably reckless driving. Generally overtaking on the wrong side (right when driving on the right) is not an offense when it is part of multilane traffic.

Comment: @MaxW & DRF: Yes, that's exacly what I mean. Sometimes even three lanes and some drivers esp. those who are impatient and fast start overtaking other car from their left. Actually they it doesn't matter from right/left side, they just want to go past the car in front quickly. So they call it "reckless driving" and "weave through traffic".

Comment: @Varun KN: Yea, like movies. 'Zooming past' you said? Is it informal then?

Comment: @Azad, yes. There are many informal things you could say when cars pass by/ overtake you in a rather reckless fashion. "Zooming past" is just an example. I hope my image (edit) graphically depicts your question.

Comment: @Azad - "weaving through traffic" would by definition be reckless driving. The notion is that you are trying to speed though traffic by switching between lanes frequently.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for your help. And thank you Varun KN for the picture. 

Comment: @MaxW would weaving through traffic always be reckless driving? It seems like it would depend on the speed and ... well recklessness. Though it might be the case that the legal situation is more black and white than I think.

Comment: @DRF In some ways, it is more black and white... in other ways, not. In some jurisdictions, vehicles in the left-hand lane are committing an offense (blocking the lane) if they are in a position where somebody is _able_ to pass them on the right (regardless of the blockers speed or the passer's speed). In some jurisdictions, weaving in and of itself is legal as long as you use the proper signals; the offense comes from the speed used when doing so... but this isn't really the venue for such minutia.

Comment: This calls for one of my favorite quips from comedian George Carlin: _Have you ever noticed that anybody driving slower than you is an idiot, and anyone going faster than you is a maniac?_

Comment:  That was a good one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the UK this is called *lane-hopping* or *weaving*.  Someone who does it is called a lane hopper.  There's no specific legal term for it, as it's covered by [Careless driving](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/legal-advice/careless-driving.html).

The US also calls this *weaving*.

[A similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80901/is-there-a-word-for-a-driver-who-changes-lanes-often) was asked on ELU.